# Are there multiple effects in the seasons?

Tags: kittens-game

I just had a cold summer in Kittens Game, which reduced my catnip field yield by 15%. Are there more different (and hopefully positive) effects? It took the whole summer before it was 'normal' again.

(I don't want to look in the faq, because I don't want to be spoiled too much)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The only thing in the game that currently checks the weather, is the getWeatherMod function, in "calendar.js", which returns 0.15 (+15% bonus) during warm seasons, and -0.15 (-15% penalty) during cold ones. Note that weather only changes when the season changes, and is added to the season's own effects; a warm spring is thus +65% to catnip, and a cold winter is -90%.

Comment: I am having a warm winter now indeed with -70%. So there are no other effects?

Comment: None at all, at least for now. The game's still in development, so it may change later.

Comment: @Mathias711 Warm winter is -60%.

Comment: @BillyMailman Just correcting another comment.

Comment: @Brilliand Oh, hey. Silly me.

Comment: @Brilliand I have no idea whether it was a typo, or it did change. I think the first option, but you are completely right of course :)